# TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertId' of undefined

Tags: html, css, mysql, node.js, express

When I run my code I get this error:

```
/Users/guohuazhang/Documents/OpenSource/app-example/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

ReferenceError: rows is not defined
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/guohuazhang/Documents/OpenSource/app-example/server/dbService.js:53:29)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/guohuazhang/Documents/OpenSource/app-example/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (/Users/guohuazhang/Documents/OpenSource/app-example/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/Users/guohuazhang/Documents/OpenSource/app-example/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/Users/guohuazhang/Documents/OpenSource/app-example/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:92:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/guohuazhang/Documents/OpenSource/app-example/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/Users/guohuazhang/Documents/OpenSource/app-example/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/Users/guohuazhang/Documents/OpenSource/app-example/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/Users/guohuazhang/Documents/OpenSource/app-example/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/guohuazhang/Documents/OpenSource/app-example/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
```

Here is the code:

```
   async insertNewName(name) {
        try {
            const dateAdded = new Date();
            const insertId = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const query = "INSERT INTO names (name, date_added) VALUES (?,?);";

                connection.query(query, [name, dateAdded] , (err, result) => {
                    if (err) reject(new Error(err.message));
                    resolve(result.insertId);
                })
            });
            return {
                id : insertId,
                name : name,
                dateAdded : dateAdded
            };
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

What's the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What does your query returns ?

Comment: Did you provide here code from near dbService.js:53? There is no `rows` entity in provided code fragment.